# Asymptotics of $\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}}$ as $|x|\to 1^+$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, asymptotics, fractional-calculus

In a study of Fractional Laplacian, I encounter the integral
$$I(x):=\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}}$$ where

1. $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb R^n$ is the $n$-dimensional unit ball centered at the origin
2. $x\in\mathbb R^n$ does not depend on $y$, $|x|>1$
3. $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is a constant.

I conjecture that $$I(x)\le C(|x|-1)^{-\alpha}\qquad (*)$$ as $|x|\to 1^+$, i.e. for $|x|>1$ sufficiently close to $1$, there exists a constant $C>0$ indepednent of $x$ such that the inequality $(*)$ holds.

Question: Is my conjecture true? If not, what is the asymptotics of $I(x)$ as $|x|\to 1^+$?

(NB: This conjecture arises in an attempt to prove *Proposition 3.1* (whose proof is omitted) in the paper *[On the superharmonicity of the first eigenfunction of the
fractional Laplacian for certain exponents](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eluis/preprints/cfe.pdf)*.)

---

### Failed Attempt

Using the reverse triangle inequality, one sees that
$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}} \\
&\le\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{dy}{||x|-|y||^{n+\alpha}} \\
&=n\cdot \text{vol}(B(0,1))\int_{0}^1\frac{r^{n-1}}{||x|-r|^{n+\alpha}} dr \qquad (1)\\
&=n\cdot \text{vol}(B(0,1))\int_{0}^1\frac{r^{n-1}}{(|x|-r)^{n+\alpha}} dr \\
&=n\cdot \text{vol}(B(0,1))\left(\frac{1}{(|x|-1)^{n+\alpha-1}}-\frac{n-1}{n+\alpha-1}\int_{0}^1\frac{r^{n-2}}{(|x|-r)^{n+\alpha-1}} dr\right) \qquad (2)\\
\end{align}$$

(1): Switching to spherical coordinates.

(2): Integrating by parts. The boundary term is $O((|x|-1)^{-n+1-\alpha})$; through integration by parts, the integral term can be shown to be $O((|x|-1)^{-n+2-\alpha})$. Thus, this bound only shows that $I(x)=O((|x|-1)^{-n+1-\alpha})$ which is weaker than the conjecture, unless $n=1$.

Comment: Rotate to a suitable coordinate system such that $x$ only has a $y_n$ component then try cylindrical coordinates i.e. decompose $dy = r^{n-2}\:dr\:d\Omega\:dy_n$ where $d\Omega$ is the measure on $S^{n-2}$

Comment: This integral is not well-defined. It is divergent for any $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @Medo $|x|>1$, so the integral is well-defined.

Comment: @Vinícius Novelli. Yes. It exists on the complement of $B(0,1)$. It blows up when $|x|\rightarrow 1^{+}$. hmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Layer cake representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation) gives
\begin{align*}
I(x)=\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}}\mathrm{d}y = (n+\alpha)\int_{0}^\infty s^{n+\alpha-1}A(s)\mathrm{d}s,
\end{align*}
where
$$
A(s)=m\left\{y\in B(0,1);|x-y|^{-1}>s \right\} = m\left(B(0,1) \cap B(x,1/s) \right).
$$
If $s>(|x|-1)^{-1}$, we have $A(s)=0$ so
$$
I(x)=(n+\alpha)\int_{0}^{(|x|-1)^{-1}}s^{n+\alpha-1}A(s)\mathrm{d}s.
$$
Bounding trivially $A(s) \leq m(B(x,s^{-1}))=c s^{-n}$, we find
\begin{align*}
I(x)&\leq c(n+\alpha)\int_{0}^{(|x|-1)^{-1}}s^{\alpha-1}\mathrm{d}s \\
&=\frac{c(n+\alpha)}{\alpha}(|x|-1)^{-\alpha},
\end{align*}
where $c=m(B(0,1))$, which is what you conjectured.

Answer (score 3):

Rotate to a suitable coordinate system such that $x$ only has a $y_n$ component and instead consider the equivalent integral with spherical coordinates centered at $x$

$$I(x)=\int_{B_1(x)}\frac{r^{n-1}\sin\theta}{r^{n+\alpha}}\:d\theta\:dr\:d\Omega$$

where $\theta$ is the "last" angular coordinate defined by $y_n = r\cos\theta$ and $d\Omega$ is the measure on $S^{n-2}$. The equation for the sphere in this coordinate system is given by

$$s^2+(y_n-x)^2 = 1$$

where $s^2+y_n^2 = r^2$. Then in our new translated spherical coordinates we have that

$$r^2-2xr\cos\theta +x^2 = 1 \implies \cos\theta = \frac{r^2+x^2-1}{2rx}$$

From here we can set up our integral

$$I(x) = \operatorname{vol}(S^{n-2})\cdot\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2+x^2-1}{2rx}\right)}\frac{\sin\theta}{r^{1+\alpha}}\:d\theta\:dr = \operatorname{vol}(S^{n-2})\cdot\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{1-(r-x)^2}{2xr^{2+\alpha}}dr$$

which, after some Mathematica (the integral is completely doable by hand though, but I don't trust myself with erroneous constants and minus signs) and reinserting understood norms, exactly evaluates to

$$I(x) =\frac{\operatorname{vol}(S^{n-2})}{2\alpha(1-\alpha^2)}\cdot\frac{1}{|x|}\cdot\left(\frac{|x|-\alpha}{(|x|-1)^\alpha}-\frac{|x|+\alpha}{(|x|+1)^\alpha}\right)$$

So your conjecture is indeed correct as when $|x|\to1^+$ the resulting expression tends to

$$\sim \frac{C_1}{(|x|-1)^\alpha}-C_2 \lesssim \frac{1}{(|x|-1)^{\alpha}}$$

for $C_1,C_2>0$.