# Does $\int_{E^c}\int_{E}\frac{dy\, dx}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}}$ converge for any $E$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

**Question:** Given an $\alpha\in(0,n)$, does there exist a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb R^n$ with $\mu(E)\in(0,\infty)$ such that  $$\int_{E^c}\int_{E}\frac{dy\, dx}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}}<+\infty$$
? (Here $E^c=\mathbb R^n\setminus E$.)

---

Background:

Currently, I am reading *Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces* and in Remark 6.6, it stated that an inequality derived earlier
$$\int_{E^c}\int_{E}\frac{dy \,dx}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}\ge C(n,s,p)\mu(E)^{\frac{n-sp}{n}}\qquad (\star)$$

can be seen as a special example of the following fractional Sobolev inequality
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}dx\,dy\ge C'(n,s,p)||f||_{L^{p^\star}(\mathbb R^n)}^{p}$$
with $f=\chi_E$, the indicator function on $E$ where $E$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with finite measure. Here, $s\in(0,1)$, $p\in[1,\infty)$, $n>sp$ and $p^\star=\frac{np}{n-sp}$. $C(n,s,p)$ denotes a constant depending only on $n,s,p$ and likewise for $C'$.

I am totally fine with the derivations. However, looking at $(\star)$, I wonder if there exists non-trivial examples of $E$ such that the L.H.S. converges; otherwise $(\star)$ is just trivial.

---

One obvious set to try is the unit ball. In @Ninad Munshi's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206572/asymptotics-of-int-b0-1-fracdyx-yn-alpha-as-x-to-1), it gives an explicit form of
$$\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha}}=\frac{\operatorname{vol}(S^{n-2})}{2\alpha(1-\alpha^2)}\cdot\frac{1}{|x|}\cdot\left(\frac{|x|-\alpha}{(|x|-1)^\alpha}-\frac{|x|+\alpha}{(|x|+1)^\alpha}\right)$$

for $\alpha\in(0,1)$. The R.H.S. is obviously not integrable over $B(0,1)^c$.

Comment: Good question ... it reminds me of this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763330/charcteristic-function-not-in-a-fractional-sobolev-space. It seems to me it should work if $\alpha\in(0,1)$ as this is equivalent $\chi_B\in H^{\alpha/2}$, no ?